C# complex Json to list<>
I try to DeserializeAnonymousType a json file with Newtonsoft.
Every thing i do is oke till the channels seccion.
user_info          - Deserialize oke
server_info        - Deserialize oke

categories, series         - Deserialize oke
categories,
movies      - Deserialize oke
categories,
live            - Deserialize oke
channels    - will not work :-( because the nummers between "" is variable
I must do something with [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "..")]
#region Properties
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
public int TvId { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
public string TvName{ get; set; }
#endregion

But i dont get it working. Here is my code:
//\**************** class1.cs *********************  
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test_Json_TV_Object

{  
    public class Data

    {   public UserInfo User_info = new UserInfo();
        public ServerInfo Server_info = new ServerInfo();
        public Categories Categories = new Categories();
        public Channels Channels = new Channels();
    }

    public class UserInfo
    {
        public int auth { get; set; }
        public string? status { get; set; }
        public string[]? allowed_output_formats { get; set; }
    }

    public class ServerInfo
    {
        public string? url { get; set; }
        public string? port { get; set; }
        public string? server_protocol { get; set; }
    }

    public class Categories
    {
        public List<Catagory_att> live = new List<Catagory_att>();
        public List<Catagory_att> movies = new List<Catagory_att>();
        public List<Catagory_att> series = new List<Catagory_att>();
        public List<Catagory_att> radio = new List<Catagory_att>();
    }

    public class Catagory_att
    {
        public string? category_id { get; set; }
        public string? category_name { get; set; }
        public int parent_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Channels
    {
        public int channel_nr { get; set; }
        public List<Channel> channelx = new List<Channel>();
    }
}

    public class Channel
    {
        public int num { get; set; }
        public string? name { get; set; }
        public string? stream_type { get; set; }
        public string? type_name { get; set; }
        public string? stream_id { get; set; }
        public string? stream_icon { get; set; }
        public int? tv_archive_duration { get; set; }
    }


//******************* form1.cs *************************
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace Test_Json_TV_Object
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string bestand = @"d:\Data\testFile.json";

        string Ret = File.ReadAllText(bestand);

        Data data = new Data();

        dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(Ret, data);

    }
  }

}



//******************* testFile.json ****************
{    "user_info":
{ "auth":1
, "status":"Active"
,
"allowed_output_formats":["m3u8","ts"]
}
,   "server_info":
{  "url":"abc.xyz"
,
"port":"80"
,
"server_protocol":"http"
}
,   "categories":
{ "series":  [
{   "category_id":"419"
,   "category_name":"SRS | TV SHOWS [EN]"                               ,
,   "parent_id":0
}
,
{   "category_id":"424"
,   "category_name":"SRS | ANIME [EN]"
,   "parent_id":0
}
,
{   "category_id":"344"
,   "category_name":"SRS | FRENCH"
,   "parent_id":0
}
,
{   "category_id":"445"
,   "category_name":"SRS | FR - ANIME"
,   "parent_id":0
}
,      { "category_id":"425", "category_name":"SRS | ARABIC [ASIA]","parent_id":0}
,      { "category_id":"355", "category_name":"SRS | ARABIC [TR] \u0645","parent_id":0}
,       { "category_id":"597", "category_name":"SRS | MALAYSIA","parent_id":0}
,       { "category_id":"347", "category_name":"SRS | DEUTSCH","parent_id":0}
,       { "category_id":"438", "category_name":"SRS | ALBANIA","parent_id":0}
,       { "category_id":"598", "category_name":"SRS | ROMANIA","parent_id":0}
,
{  "category_id":"773"
,  "category_name":"SRS | DOMACE SERIJE [EXYU]"
,    "parent_id":0
}
]
, "movies":     [
{  "category_id":"266"
,  "category_name":"VOD | EN LATEST MOVIES"
,  "parent_id":0
}
,
{  "category_id":"422"
,  "category_name":"VOD | NETFLIX [EN]"
,"parent_id":0
}
,     { "category_id":"423", "category_name":"VOD | DISNEY+ [EN]","parent_id":0}
,     { "category_id":"476", "category_name":"VOD | MARVEL [EN]" ,"parent_id":0}
,     { "category_id":"480", "category_name":"VOD | DC [EN]","parent_id":0}
]
,  "live":         [
{   "category_id":"580", "category_name":"VIP | FORMULA 1","parent_id":0}
,      {  "category_id":"373", "category_name":"EU | FRANCE GENERAL","parent_id":0}
,      { "category_id":"363", "category_name":"EU | FRANCE SPORTS","parent_id":0}
,      { "category_id":"589", "category_name":"EU | FR AMAZON PRIME","parent_id":0}
,      { "category_id":"546", "category_name":"IN | MARATHI","parent_id":0}
]
}
,  "channels":    {    "69241":     { "num":1
,  "name":"##### MY - MALAYSIA #####"
,  "stream_type":"live"
,  "type_name":"Live Streams"
,  "stream_id":"69241"
,   "tv_archive_duration":0
}
,    "260551":  { "num":3
,  "name":"MY - FRANCE24"
,   "stream_type":"live"
,  "type_name":"Live Streams"
,  "stream_id":"260551"
,  "tv_archive_duration":0
}
, "260553":    {  "num":4
,  "name":"MY - DW"
,  "stream_type":"live"
,  "type_name":"Live Streams"
,  "stream_id":"260553"
,  "tv_archive_duration":0
}
,   "260554":  { "num":5
,  "name":"MY - SKY NEWS"
,   "stream_type":"live"
,  "type_name":"Live Streams"
,  "stream_id":"260554"
,  "tv_archive_duration":0
}
}
}
//***********************************************************************************

i tryed somthing like this :
   dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(Ret, data);

Ret = is the json text
data = the list with the total class
var Test1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Ret)
var Test2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<channels>(Ret);

You would be well served using a more standard set of naming conventions perhaps.  What you think is a property defined class property of public List<Channel> channelx = new List<Channel>(); here is going to hurt your efforts also over a get/set definition

Note: public string? category_name { get; set; } string is a reference and always nullable Might I suggest public string CategoryName { get; set; } instead

Can you reduce this down to say just the Channels/Channel since the concepts should be the same?  I cannot see where public int TvId { get; set; } applies to any of the rest of the presented code here for example.

Change the definition of your channels class to:
public class Channels
{
    public Dictionary<string, Channel> ChannelList { get; set; }
}

or
public class Channels
{
    public Dictionary<string, Channel> ChannelList = new Dictionary<string, channel>();
}

This will associate the single numerical element with the channel object.

Thanks Kevin i use the
public Dictionary<string, Channel> ChannelList { get; set; }
and now its works
another problem was that there was a problem in the json string that a item sometimes a int and sometimes a string is, now i declared my class item as a object and can read my json correct.
 public class Channel
{
    public object?  num { get; set; }   //int or string
    public string? name { get; set; }
    public string? stream_type { get; set; }
 }


@AdeV. - you should ask another question about that. The format for questions on stack overflow is one question per post, so you should ask another question (and accept this answer, if it does indeed answer your original question).
